# How to add CSS code dynamically using PHP?

Tags: php, css

I have this sample:

**CODE PHP**

```
<?php Zend_Debug::dump($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description')); exit; ?>
```

that return this string

```
string(345) "<p>With glossy, raven-black frames, the <strong>Coleman</strong> frames command attention. With a slightly wider frame, narrow bridge, and more rounded line, you&rsquo;ll feel stylish and modern. Their bold, elegant, raven-black color is every bit the classic look. But their high style and lightweight feel hit just the right modern note.</p>
```

I want to manipulate this string, so to be of the following form:

```
string(345) "<p>With glossy, raven-black frames, the <strong style="font-size: echo $myvar; ">Coleman</strong> frames command attention. With a slightly wider frame, narrow bridge, and more rounded line, you&rsquo;ll feel stylish and modern. Their bold, elegant, raven-black color is every bit the classic look. But their high style and lightweight feel hit just the right modern note.</p>
```

Basically I want to add css style for my php string.

How can I do this dynamically?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are working on a string here, so use the string functions, like `str_replace` or `preg_replace` for example to replace a part. If you want to apply this style to all `<strong>` tags in your string, replace '<strong>' by '<strong style="blablabla">'

Comment: Dont magento nuts normally edit `catalog/product/view/description.phtml`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you store your string in $str variable. Then:

```
str_replace("<strong>", "<strong style='font-size: " . $myvar . "'>", $str);
```